# Unsupported type 'add-resource' in Android Studio

Tags: android, types, gradle

I encountered a resource merging issue when running a `gradle build` command.

Logs as below:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':frameworks:base:core:res:res-common:packageReleaseResources'.> Unsupported type 'add-resource' in file .../kk4_4/frameworks/base/core/res/res-common/res/values-XXX/dimens.xml

Environment:

- Android Studio: 0.5.8
- Android Plugin: 0.10.+
- Gradle Version: all damned from 1.10 to 1.12

Resource:

```xml
<add-resource type="dimen" name="slidingmenu_menu_width"/>
<dimen name="slidingmenu_menu_width">232dip</dimen>

<add-resource type="dimen" name="card_list_item_padding_left" />
<dimen name="card_list_item_padding_left">13.5dip</dimen>
```

These `<add-resource />` nodes are used for overlays in aapt, and I wonder if there's a way to pass gradle builds without removing them?

Comment: This is probably worth filing a bug at https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/entry?template=Android%20Studio%20bug

Comment: @ScottBarta , thanks for your advice, and issue was opened [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=69718), and I want to replace all these 'add-resource' nodes to empty strings "" before merging resources in gradle build task, is this gonna work and how?

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this problem myself, here is the result:
add-resource node is not supported when using android plugin 0.8.+ or later
If we change

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.5.+'
}
```

and use gradle 1.8 instead of the later versions

run gradle tasks in terminal, and all tasks turn to success

but the 'Gradle Sync' function will not work properly in the latest Android Studio,

Hope google deals with it soon.