# Error: Unsupported type 'Add-resource' in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am migrating the Eclipse project to Android Studio now.
When I build the project I get the following error at `gradle`.

```
\...\res\values\strings.xml

>"Error: Unsupported type 'add-resource'"
```

The problem line of `strings.xml` is :

```
<add-resource type="string" name="default_folder_name" />
```

How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Open `strings.xml` and search for `add-resource`.

Comment: post your string.xml file

Comment: I think eclipse would have a problem with that line in your strings.xml also

Comment: Please [check this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23680156/unsupported-type-add-resource-in-android-studio) answer.

Answer (score 7):

`<add-resources>` is a platform only features.

> add-resource is used when using overlays in aapt (where it'll complain
>   about overriden values unless you use add-resource), while we
>   automatically enable overriding in our merger. Replacing it with `<item ...>` should work. ~ [Xavier Ducrohet](https://plus.google.com/101141978306189669992/posts/bHMyCTVwCw1)

Instead of this,

```
<add-resource type="string" name="default_folder_name" />
```

use this,

```
<string name="default_folder_name"/>
```

Also, instead of this,

```
<add-resource type="dimen" name="custom_cling_margin_top" />
<add-resource type="dimen" name="custom_cling_margin_right" />
<add-resource type="dimen" name="custom_cling_margin_left" />
```

use this,

```
<dimen name="custom_cling_margin_top"/>
<dimen name="custom_cling_margin_right"/>
<dimen name="custom_cling_margin_left"/>
```